# Running verbose cmake tests in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, ctest

I have a placeholder test setup with cmake and I'm using the Visual Studio (2017) integration. How can I run a test in verbose mode from within VS?

[Test Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYqFf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you run the test, VS shows an "Output" button in the task explorer where you can see all the test outputs.